# Magento product quantity as radio buttons

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have an installation of magento 1.7.0.2.

I am looking for a way to add the product qty as radio buttons for customers.

For example I will remove the input text field qty and instead have maybe 5 radio buttons where customer can choose qty, see below

5 Items
10 Items
20 Items
30 Items

I have been looking for a way to do this via the admin panel but cannot see any option for this and searched online for any changes that need to be made to the code.

Any suggestions on how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $n=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){ ?>
<input type="radio" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks Dushyant Joshi, in which file should I amend this code?

Comment: It depends on your templates. It can be applied anywhere means in view.phtml etc

Comment: Thanks Dushyant Joshi, i'm almost there. How do I set the qty for each of the radio buttons, for example the first one will add 5 product, then second 10, next 20 etc. And I need to add a label for each.